# changing a string and list of list into a string

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, spyder

This is what I have printed in an output file called 'output.txt':

```
5 [[ 1  2  23  12  6]
 [ 3  4 5  6 7]
 [1 1 1  2 1]
 [ 25 26  27 28 29]
 [ 1  1 0 1 3]]
```

This is the string that I want to have:

```
5
1 2 23 12 6
3 4 5 6 7
1 1 1 2 1
25 26 27 28 29
1 1 0 1 3
```

(5 is the number of columns and rows).
I've tried doing split('[]') and " ".join(), but they both don't work. What code do I need to change this?

** The numbers inside the list are random numbers that I just made up

Comment: Please post your code, and the output.

Comment: Is this in a file? Or is it a multi-line string (`"""`)

Comment: is it a list or a string?

Comment: This question is currently impossible to answer because it entirely depends on how the "this is what I have" part is stored in the first place, and you have totally left that out.

Comment: it is written onto a created output file called 'output.txt'.

Answer (score 1):

If it is in a multi-line string (`"""`):

```
>>> data = """5 [[ 1  2  23  12  6]                                                                                                           ...  [ 3  4 5  6 7]
...  [1 1 1  2 1]
...  [ 25 26  27 28 29]
...  [ 1  1 0 1 3]]"""
>>> print ' '.join([item for item in ''.join(data.split('\n')).replace('[[', '\n').replace('[', '').replace(']', '\n').split(' ') if len(item)]).replace('\n ', '\n').replace('\n\n', '')
5 
1 2 23 12 6
3 4 5 6 7
1 1 1 2 1
25 26 27 28 29
1 1 0 1 3
>>>
```

This parses the data using some `join`s, `replace`s, and `split`s.

---

If it is in a list:

```
>>> data = [[1, 2, 23, 12, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 1, 1, 2, 1], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [1, 1, 0, 1, 3]]
>>> def foo(data):
...     print len(data)
...     for i in data:
...             print ' '.join([str(item) for item in i])
... 
>>> foo(data)
5
1 2 23 12 6
3 4 5 6 7
1 1 1 2 1
25 26 27 28 29
1 1 0 1 3
>>>
```

Comment: What if it's in a text file? That's what I meant with my last comment and why the question is too broad: you shouldn't have to have a 4- or 5-part answer covering all your guesses at what OP meant.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist fair enough

Comment: It's in a file, which I already suspected. I think this is homework, hence the "5" at the beginning to show you the length of the list (so you don't have to calculate it, even though that's very easy). I have nominated the question for reopening, but in the meantime I think if you add part 3: "if it's in a file" to your answer it's worth accepting.